# Can I own a car in Switzerland, without living in Switzerland?

Tags: united-kingdom, switzerland, car

I am from Sweden, I live in Switzerland and I am moving to London. I have a car in Switzerland that I am not yet sure what to do with. I like it and I want to keep it. However, I am not sure what my best option is. So what I am wondering is if it's possible to own a car in Switzerland without living in Switzerland.

When I moved from Sweden to Switzerland I used my Swedish car for a year in Switzerland and I am basically wondering if I could do the same when I move from Switzerland to the United Kingdom.

Comment: Do you want to take the car with you to the UK, or have it parked somewhere in Switzerland for use when you visit?

Comment: My intention is to take it to the UK and simply decide later whether it makes more sense to import it to the UK or sell it in Switzerland. Like I did with my Swedish car when I moved to Switzerland.

Comment: Once you are a resident in the UK (or any other EU country for that matter) you cannot **legally** drive your non-local car (there are some exceptions, but none of them seem to apply to you)! [More details here](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk-for/59#59)

Comment: I feel that this question is not a duplicate, because it mainly focuses on Switzerland, not the UK.

Comment: @SztupY this depends a lot on the EU states involved. I got pulled over in Germany with Italian plates (had residence in both states at the time) and was told that even as a German resident I could drive a car with foreign plates as long as I paid tax on it. Another example: Lithuania requires being registered as a resident to get a permanent car registration there, while Italy is less strict: any EU citizen who declares their regular abode to be in Italy can register a car in Italy, as long as they pay taxes there.