# How long can a student drive an EU registered car in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

I am an 18 year old Maltese student studying at the Warsash Martine Academy and I was wondering if it is possible to drive my EU registered car in the UK for a period of 7 to 8 months.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long can I drive a EU registered car in the UK for?](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk-for)

Comment: @Gagravarr The specific cases of students is only discussed in comments, maybe it's valuable to keep it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

As detailed in the answer to [How long can I drive a EU-registered car in the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk-for) residents usually cannot drive a car registered abroad at all.

But under EU law, students are supposed to be exempt from the general rules so you should be able to drive your Malta-registered car in the UK for the whole time. The UK does not seem very sympathetic to the idea, though. This possibility used to be mentioned on this [gov.uk page](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports) but as of December 2014, it only covers temporary imports *from outside the EU*.

Answer (score 1):

As above, you can use your car in the UK for the period of your study, but you would need car insurance, which IS available in the UK, from several companies who specialise in EU student cars.(GOOGLE)
     My son is a student on Malta with his car, but as yet have not found an Insurance company that will insure him!