# Using an EU car in the UK as a student

Tags: united-kingdom, students

There are already two questions ([How long can a student drive an EU registered car in the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/how-long-can-a-student-drive-an-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk) and [How long can I drive a EU-registered car in the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk)) on site site regarding using an EU registered car in the UK, however, I think my case is somewhat different.

I am an EU citizen (German nationality) and I am currently doing my Ph.D. in the UK. In order to be exempt from paying the German health care system, I have unregistered my residency in Germany (and subsequently registered residency in the UK).

I have brought a German-registered car to the UK. This car is insured (and taxed) in Germany. It is owned by my parents, who are still living in germany.

My question boils down to:

> Am I required to register, tax, and/or insure this car in the UK assuming that I will keep it there no longer than the period of my Ph.D. ?

I have found varying information online regarding this matter. Specifically, on `europa.eu` there is an exemption clause listed for students (link below):

> [**Exceptions to compulsory registration after 6 months**](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/taxes/index_en.htm)
>
> If you are staying in another country only in order to study, you can drive your car without having to register it or pay taxes there - for as long as you are enrolled in an educational establishment in that country.

This seems to be derived from [Council directive of 28 March 1983 Article 5 1b](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:31983L0182:en:HTML), a rule which is quoted by [other](http://intsupport.southwales.ac.uk/driving/) [sources](http://www.exeter.ac.uk/internationalstudents/uklife/driving/).

The way I see it, there are three pieces:

- taxation (road tax)
- registration (license plates)
- insurance

However, none of the sources which I have found online give a clear picture for either one of those pieces. Event more troubling is that the gouvernment website [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports) does not list an exemption for EU students. I have not found any specific information on how the situation changes if the car owner is not a UK resident and not the person driving the car.

Comment: What do you mean with “registered residency in the UK”?

Comment: Did you ask your German insurance company whether they will cover the cost of accidents if you drive the car while being a resident in the UK?

Comment: Do you know what are the new rules since Brexit.
It is not clear if student from the EU are still exempt for registration or not.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find a proper reference on either the EU-Lex site or the Gov.UK sites but couldn't find anything definitive, so this might be speculation, but I think if you are not registered in Germany anymore (and you are a UK resident) you **cannot** drive a German car, even if you are only a student in the UK.

I think the original EU law allows students to use their cars abroad, is because students (similarly to cross border workers) are **not considered as a resident** in the new country. This unclearness can also lead to other types of confusions for students, for example [check my answer on whether you are allowed to get an EHIC or not as a student](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/confusion-about-ehic-for-a-student-in-the-uk/5686#5686). There the problem is the same: as a student your residency status between your home and host country is not clear inside the EU (as by default as a student you are still considered as a resident in your home country).

But in your case this is also not true, as you have already said you have de-registered from Germany and you are an (ordinary) resident in the UK. Based on my interpretation this means you are not allowed to drive a non-UK registered car in the UK.

While as I've said this is mostly speculation as neither the EU-Lex site nor the Gov.UK site has anything concrete to say about this issue, some universities in the UK think similarly: after 6 months you are probably a resident, and you should re-register your car in the UK ([source 1](http://intsupport.southwales.ac.uk/driving/)) ([source 2](http://www.exeter.ac.uk/internationalstudents/uklife/driving/)).