# Driving a Polish registered leased vehicle in England as a resident

Tags: united-kingdom, vehicle-registration

My friend has recently moved from Poland to England. She is currently driving a polish registered leased vehicle, is it necessary to have UK Road Tax and who's responsibility is it to obtain it, furthermore as it stands is she legally entitled drive it in the UK?

Comment: This changes very often and its best to call `00443007906802` and ask the TAX department or somebody at GOV.UK

Comment: See http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk?rq=1 There is actually an exception for **short term** leases from EU countries, but if he is trying to settle down I guess he needts to re-register the car as a UK one (which might not be possible as it's a lease)