# Help! I'm buying a car registered in Slovakia for use in Spain and the Uk

Tags: eu, spain, insurance, vehicle-registration

I am buying a motor home that has Slovakian Plates it has been in the UK for 2 months and I will have it here for 3 weeks then take it to Spain. How can I insure it?

The owner is legit and has all the relevant documents. But I'm getting conflicting advice DVLA say I may need to insure it in Slovakia AND the U.K.! The Slovakian police have said I need to go in person to Slovakia!

I ultimately want to register it in Spain but it's getting very complex!

Comment: Where are you resident at the moment? Are you moving to Spain?

Comment: Related http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk/59#59 and http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/can-a-car-be-registered-in-two-eu-countries-at-the-same-time?rq=1

Comment: Your place of residence is really crucial here. If you are a Spanish resident, a Spanish insurer might cover you even with Slovakian plates. If you are a UK resident it might even be flatly illegal for you to drive the vehicle, no matter where you insure it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the UK, and only want insurance for the UK and Spain, you can re-register the vehicle in the UK as an imported vehicle.  It would then be issued with a "Q" prefix number plate.

( This is relatively common across the EU.   Germany (certainly used to) require vehicles owned by ex-pat residents to be re-registered with German plates, for example. See also: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/registration/taxes/index_en.htm
)

The vehicle is then a UK vehicle, and you can do all your insuring in the UK, or in the UK and Spain.

https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/vat-and-tax-vehicles-from-within-the-eu

This is not a legal *requirement* as long as:

> You don’t need to report the arrival of the vehicle using NOVA if any of the following apply:
>
> the vehicle is in the UK for less than 6 months in a 12-month period and you normally live in the EU (one single visit, or several shorter visits adding up to a 6-month period)

It takes 4 weeks to complete the process, generally speaking.

Comment: As Spain will have an analogous system, perhaps you could contact Spain, and have it registered there, and insured from there, from the off?