# UK resident driving foreign-registered car

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, vehicle-registration

Following information found here:

[How long can I drive a EU-registered car in the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-long-can-i-drive-a-eu-registered-car-in-the-uk)

I have a question on this bit:

> lease an EU-registered car and use this temporarily in the UK

What does it mean? Does it cover car rented in another EU country from private owner (with rental agreement on paper and valid under this EU country law)? The information found in the answer to the question I link to (https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/59) is no longer displayed on gov.uk and there are no references to the legislation to be found anywhere.