# Can I drive a car in the UK if it's leased in Italy and I am resident in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, car

My car is leased in Italy and I would like to bring it to the UK, but I can't register it there since I am not the owner of the car and the leasing company won't allow me to change the plates. Can I drive it without having to register it if I am resident in the UK?

Comment: Why not lease a car in the UK?  You'll have the steering wheel on the right, which is preferable when driving on the left.

Comment: @gerrit I'm not sure.  I have driven in left-side-of-the-road countries only very little, but I found that the different physical relationship between me and the steering-wheel-on-the-right car was far more troublesome than the different traffic patterns or sight lines.  That is, I was tending to keep my body in the left part of the lane as if driving a "normal" (for me) car.  As a consequence, the car's left wheels were continually running off the left side of the road.  I also scratched the left side of the car when trying to park at the airport.

Comment: @phoog I had exactly the same problem. I haven't driven a LHD car in a left-driving country but I can't imagine it's much better. One gets used to driving a RHD car.

Comment: I can confirm @phoog's experience. Very annoying, and resulted in a lot "watch out, the ditch!" from my passenger. :)

Comment: This might be related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/50/6777 – essentially that says your answer is a clear **no**.