# Can a British-license holder drive an EU registered car in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, eu-citizens, car, driving

I'll be moving abroad in November and planning to get my car from EU to the UK this or next month before we move, so that I can drive all the way there. Do I need to register the car here with temporary plates? My license is British, but the car is not. Although registered, taxed and MOTed in its country of origin. Can I drive it here in the UK on this case?

Comment: This existing answer may help: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/59/17166

Comment: @Andre Laranjo Does https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports answer your question?